# Send host system to hibernation from within the guest

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8.1, virtualbox, hibernate

**Host:** Windows 8.1 **Guest:** Windows XP **VirtualBox:** 5.1.8

From within the host I can press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and enter `shutdown.exe` which is a little app to send the host to sleep (while the guest is running).

Is it possible to call this executable from within the guest programmatically?

Comment: `shutdown.exe` **shuts down** the Windows system. Sleep is something different.

Comment: In prnciple, yes you can run commands on the host from the guest, in the same ways you can run commands on another computer across a network. (There are no special features in VirtualBox to enable this.) If you have a virtual network between the guest and the host you could remote login (I would use `ssh` between *nix systems) and run any authorised commands.

Comment: @JoeP: Sorry, I forgot to tell that I'm using `shutdown.exe /h`, but thanks for your feedback!